# Defining Folder editor change to folder

Tags: vba, excel, directory, uppercase, lowercase

I have a problem with declaring `Folder` objects.

I'm trying to type `plik_zip` `Folder`, but VBA editor (in Excel 2013) converts it to `folder`

```
Sub Submitt()
    Dim plik_zip As folder
```

Reference changing makes no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`folder` is not a type in your case and besides VBA is not case sensitive.

Perhaps you want to do something like this:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Get the folder object 
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Temp")
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBE will do this if you declared a variable named `folder` *anywhere* else in your code.  You can "correct" (VBA is not case sensitive) the case it uses by typing `Dim Folder` on an empty line, move the cursor off the line, then delete it. It will use the case of the last variable you declared, regardless of scope.

Note that having objects declared as 'folder' makes no difference to the compiler, but in general I avoid using the names of types as variable for this very reason.

Comment: I have made new file and manually rewrite all without variable folder and works fine, THX :D

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode without any other code in your Excel you after you type `Dim f As FolDer` it will never change.

Now add a new line like this:

```
Dim folder As Object
```

Then, It will change that line to:

Dim f As folder

Now, Delete all codes! now add this code again: `Dim f As FolDer` you will see it changes to `Dim f As folder` !!!

This will be repeated until you close the Excel.

This is a cause of caching variable names in VBE.